# Data Validation List Clear

Tags: excel, vba, validation

Currently I have three fields of data. Two are data validation lists and another is just a normal cell where I input a number value. Once I've selected the data I want, I press an ActiveX button which copies the data into another spreadsheet. What it currently looks like:
[image: What it currently looks like]

The issue I have is I want on the button press for the fields to clear but retain their information. I've tried both .Clear and .ClearContents but they completely remove my data validation lists. I just want them to go back to a blank state for the next time.

What I want it to reset to:
[image: What I want it to reset to]

Is there any way of doing this or do I need to rethink the entire spreadsheet and use VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA : If `myCell` is the cell which you want to clear, use

```
 myCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
```

*Edit*: after comments below and assuming that the 3 fields from the screenshots above are `c4`, `c7` and `c10` I would recommend to change your sub like this:

```
Private Sub Command5Button21_Click()
    Dim s1, s2
    Set s1 = Worksheets("Master")
    Set s2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With s1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
        .Cells(, "a").Value = s2.Range("p20").Value
        .Cells(, "b").Value = s2.Range("p21").Value
        .Cells(, "c").Value = s2.Range("c4").Value
        .Cells(, "d").Value = s2.Range("c7").Value
        .Cells(, "e").Value = s2.Range("c10").Value
        s2.Range("c4").FormulaR1C1 = ""
        s2.Range("c7").FormulaR1C1 = ""
        s2.Range("c10").FormulaR1C1 = ""
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So in the button I put in that line? It will clear it and retain the data validation dropdown list?

Comment: Yes. In the callback of the Button.

Comment: Apologies @Maksim but I'm not too familiar with how to write this. I added the line into my code but nothing happened.

Comment: Can you please share your code ? This would probably help the community to help you. Copy the line above to the end of the sub which gets executed when the button is pressed.

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim s1, s2

    Set s1 = Worksheets("Master")
    Set s2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With s1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow

        .Cells(, "a").Value = s2.Range("p20").Value
        .Cells(, "b").Value = s2.Range("p21").Value
        .Cells(, "c").Value = s2.Range("c4").Value
        .Cells(, "d").Value = s2.Range("c7").Value
        .Cells(, "e").Value = s2.Range("c10").Value
        
        
    End With


End Sub

Comment: OK. Is "Field 1" represented by s2.Range("c4") ? The same holds for the other fields : Can you specify which cells are labelled by "Enter Dollar Amount" and "Reason"? C7 and C10 ? If so, then look into the modified answer above.